# IoC Container for WPF application

Tags: wpf, ioc-container, structuremap

I'd like to start using IoC Container in an existing WPF application.
I need good performance, but from what I read, performance is really not an issue with most containers.
What I need most is a very easy to use container, that can be easily integrated into my app. I read recommendations about StructureMap (and the syntax looks great), but in their site it seems that there were no updates in the last 3 years, so I'm having some doubts about it.

Please provide recommendations with basic usage code samples (initialization + usage).

**Edit**
I'm not looking for a complete framework. I only need the IoC container ability, so many other alternatives exist. The last relevant discussion I found here is a few years old and I'd like to refresh it.

Comment: Easy and fast? Try [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com) (shameless plug).

Comment: I read about Simple Injector and saw it runs on `SilverLight`. Will there be any problem in `WPF` apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer really depends on personal preference and the details of your use case. Anyway, after using Unity, MEF (I know, not a real IoC container) and writing some individual solutions, I am now using [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation) and like it a lot. It is very easy to dig into and continuously reveals its advantages the longer you use it. It provides a fluent interface and is fast, compared to other frameworks (btw: The performance of your container can be a very important issue, depending on what you want to do). For usage and samples of Autofac see the link above.

Why I like it:

- Easy to get into
- Fluent interface
- Supports open generics
- Supports assembly scanning
- Interoperability with MEF and other frameworks
- Fast enough ([Performance comparison of IoC containers](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison))

Still, this is personal choice and there are other good solutions around, which might even be better for your special case.

And, more or less off-topic, I can recommend this article, especially the second half, for general considerations. It helped me a lot. So, just in case:

[Article by Martin Fowler](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. I read Fowler's article. The main resistance to using a container in our code is because it's "black magic". I want to show that it is very easy to use and understand.

Comment: Black magic is frowned upon. :/
I'd really like to be the magician though.

Comment: @Noich: True, if you look at it historically, it has always been a bit of an issue to be a magician. Anyway, it's all about knowing your tricks. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Structuremap aint [dead](http://jeremydmiller.com/2013/02/22/big-update-on-structuremap-3-0-progress).

We are using it for our new green field project, and when v3 is out we may migrate to it. ATM using 2.6.4.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a shopping-list type question so it won't stay open long.

There are a number of IoC type frameworks, some of which require declarative or programmatic manipulation to do their work, some of which use code semantics to wire things up.

I would suggest you start with [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921141%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup> until you get into the swing of things, then look to branch out into some of the more [exotic frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1280978/109702) when you can appreciate the differences between them.

<sup>1</sup> Here is a good recent intro article: *[Visual Studio magazine: Creating Modularity with WPF, Prism and Unity](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/07/01/creating-modularity-with-wpf-prism-and-unity.aspx)*